# How to enable HTTP response caching in the DownloadManager?

Tags: android

I want repeat requests for a URL to be served from a local cache, not re-downloaded from the server.  I'm using the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html), hoping it'll be a convenient alternative to `HttpURLConnection` ([saw it recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/2402790)), but it does no response caching by default.  Here's my test code:

```
final Context context = getContext();
final DownloadManager manager =
  Android.ensureSystemService( DownloadManager.class, context );
final DownloadManager.Request req =
  new DownloadManager.Request( Uri.parse( BIG_FILE_URL ));
req.setNotificationVisibility( VISIBILITY_HIDDEN ); // hiding from user
context.registerReceiver( new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive( final Context context, final Intent intent )
    {
        context.unregisterReceiver( this ); // one shot for this test
        final long id = intent.getLongExtra( EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1L );
        System.err.println( " --- downloaded id=" + id );
        System.err.println( " --- uri=" +
          manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(id) );
    }
}, new IntentFilter( ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE ));
manager.enqueue( req );
```

Running the above test twice, I see two `GET` requests at the remote server (each with a `200` response) and the following in the local Android log:

```
20:14:27.574 D/DownloadManager( 1591): [1] Starting
20:14:28.256 D/DownloadManager( 1591): [1] Finished with status SUCCESS
20:14:28.263 W/System.err( 2203):  --- downloaded id=1
20:14:28.269 W/System.err( 2203):  --- uri=content://downloads/my_downloads/1
20:15:13.904 D/DownloadManager( 1591): [2] Starting
20:15:14.517 D/DownloadManager( 1591): [2] Finished with status SUCCESS
20:15:14.537 W/System.err( 2203):  --- downloaded id=2
20:15:14.541 W/System.err( 2203):  --- uri=content://downloads/my_downloads/2
```

So it downloaded `BIG_FILE` twice and stored it in two files.  Instead I want response caching.  Can the `DownloadManager` do response caching?

---

PS. It looks like ‘no’.  So I corrected the recommendation that brought me here ([see rev 22](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3028660/revisions)).

PPS. To be certain, I tested a standard [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html).  It has no effect on the `DownloadManager`, though it does enable caching by default for each `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

DownloadService downloads to a temporary destination by default. There is no build-in ability to cache requests, however you can query the list of downloads requested before with [DownloadManager.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#query%28android.app.DownloadManager.Query%29) method.

Comment: Caching involves the HTTP protocol. The query facility won't give me that kind of coordination. I can't add a proper cache outside the box. (I should know better than to even *look* at a big box convenience like DownloadManager. It always proves a waste of time.)